# template tag slice won't work while truncatechars works

Tags: python, django

season1-theOffice. I want to remove -theOffice. Thus I did season1|truncatechars: "9" but with this it gives season 1...
I don't want to see ... 
So I used season1|slice:" :9" but this does nothing. 
Here's my code.

```
        <a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=all_episode.season.slug %}">{{ all_episode.season|slice:":5" }}
```

My fulll code

```
<div class="row">
  {% for all_episode in episode %}
    <div class="col-6 card" style="padding:20px">
      <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">
        <img class="card-img-top" src='{{all_episode.image.url}}'>
      </a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">{{ all_episode.title }}</a>
        </h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ all_episode.story |slice:":100" }}...</p>
      </div>

      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          <span class="h5">
            <a href="{% url 'series_detail' slug=all_episode.series.slug %}">{{ all_episode.series }}</a>
          </span> / 
          <span class="h6">
            <a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=all_episode.season.slug %}">{{ all_episode.season|slice:":9" }}     </a>
          </span>
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have added a *space* in your template filter (or at least in the question text, like `slice:" :9"`).

You should write it like:

```
{{ all_episode.season|slice:":-9" }}
```

not:

```
{{ all_episode.season|slice:" :-9" }}
```

The `-9` means that you count from the end of the string to the start of the string, so here we will omit `9` characters. `-1` would thus remove the last character.

For example:

```
>>> Template('{{ s|slice:":-9" }}').render(Context({'s': 'season1-theOffice'}))
'season1-'
```

Comment: I tried it but it still won't work.....I uploaded my full code. do you mind taking a peak at it?

Comment: @rosababy: but you did not use `-9`, but `9`?

Comment: I tried both of them but same result, I'm thinking to use cut. is there a way to put multple cuts? so like OR in django jinja2?

Comment: actually the one i suggested up is a bad way.........is custom template tag the only way?